# Hugo: Javascript commands not working till after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, hugo

I am working on a Hugo Static Site Generator theme, the problem is that the Javascript features don't load unless I reload the page

e.g 
Before reloading the page
[image: Page before loading]

After reloading the page

[image: Page after loading]

This is the code, I used in adding the new class

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('h2').addClass('hello')
       });
```

Now, the problem is that since it is a static site generator when opening a new page, it will not refresh/reload the site, but load the page like a cached page. therefore most of the javascript features only apply once unless the page is reloaded. The problem is also experienced when I am using VueJs on the theme, Which means, I need to find a way to force load a new URL, instead of it loading like an anchor link.

**UPDATE:** I have been able to resolve it, The problem was from another javascript file, making an ajax get request
Thanks

Comment: may be your code runs before loading the h2

Comment: wrap your code inside ` document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   // add class here 
   console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });`

Comment: Still same behaviour, I have to reload before the static site be reflect the change

Comment: Are you caching the JS files?

Comment: No, I am not caching the JS files

Comment: What console errors are you seeing, before and after?

Comment: Actually, those console errors are just errors from an extension (Not much of an error though)

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug or add console.log inside your ready function to see it can reach there? I am suspecting that your h2 is rendered by js and at the time your code to add class hello that h2 is not rendered yet.

If this is the case I think you need to render html at server first or you can include your script in the same place as your components

Comment: This I have done, all js commands only show or run after reloading the page, by rendering the HTML at server first (I don't understand how to do that), including my script in the same place as my components (I am making use of Hugo static site generator, and using markdown, so for a start, I need the changes to be applied to all the markdowns, when the content is loaded)

Comment: can I see what it looks like for your html from server?